# How to get the sum of an particular column of telerik ListView?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, telerik, radlistview

hi can anyone help me with this i want to convert this webform code to used with telerik control,

```
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;

    try
    {
        j = ListView1.Items.Count;
        for (i = 0; i <= j - 1; i++)
        {
            k = k + Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return k;
}
```

basically i need to get the sum of a particluar column from a list view which is in telerik so if anyone can help me out please do help Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"i want to convert this webform code to used with telerik control"_ What is the specific problem?

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 actually i am porting a standard webform project to telerik so i have to make few changes in the code so far i have done 90% for the overall project but now i am strucked with the listbox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so here is the solution itself thanks @checho for helping me out really appreciate your help

```
  foreach (ListViewDataItem item in radListView1.Items)
            {
                //k += (int)item["Column 1"].ToString();
                //this code helped me 

                k += Convert.ToInt32(item["Column 1"].ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RadListView from the Telerik UI for Winforms suite, here is how to access the values of the items in the different cells in the control:

```
        int i = 0;
        foreach (ListViewDataItem item in radListView1.Items)
        {
            i += (int)item["YourColumnName"];
        }
```

Comment: appreciate your help @checho but i does not seem to be working out since my column name is **Total Price** after making the necessary changes in the code it throws an error  **Object Reference Not set to instance of object** 

            **k += (int)item["Total Price"]**

Comment: It appears that in your case the column Name = "Column 1". This can be checked by breaking at the row with the exception and checking item[0].Name, item[1].Name, etc, until you find the needed column.